# Why cast an object that's already been identified as a particular class?

Tags: java

In the following code, assuming that the method `equals` belongs to class `Rectangle`, I'm wondering why it's necessary to cast the parameter `object` as a rectangle when the `if` condition has already established that `object` is a rectangle.

```
public boolean equals(Object object)
{
   boolean equal;
   if (object != null && this.getClass() ==
      object.getClass())
   {
      Rectangle other = (Rectangle) object;
      equal = (this.width == other.width) &&
         (this.height == other.height);
   }
   else
   {
      equal = false;
   }
   return equal;
}
```

Comment: Because the language syntax doesn't care what `if` clauses you have. It doesn't "read" the code like a human.

Comment: Because the static type ob `object` is `Object`. You cannot change the static type of a variable in Java.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, but the `if` code only runs if the object is a Rectangle, so why the need to cast it as a Rectangle? I don't see what syntax has to do with it.

Comment: Because the code is **compiled** and it's a syntax error at compile time. The compiler doesn't care about when or if your `if` clause runs at all. It just sees that you're trying to do an assignment without a cast, and it causes a syntax error.

Comment: @Kayaman I don't see the rationale for why the compiler would complain. The `if` clause will run if and only if `object` is a rectangle. It will thus have `width` and `height` fields.

Comment: @yroc I already told you. The compiler doesn't care about the `if` clause. But you're not going to understand this anyway. You might want to read up on language typing (strong typing, duck typing etc.).

Comment: Yes, you already told me the compiler doesn't care about the `if` clause. I learned something new and helpful -- thank you. But my follow question was _why_ the compiler wouldn't care; that's a different question. Anyway I'll have a look at the references you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Doesn't this.getClass() == object.getClass() ensure that object is a rectangle?**

No. What that statement does, is return a boolean based on that operation. The only way to "ensure" that an object is of a certain type, is to initialize the variable as such, or try to cast it into that type.

Think of this from the compiler's perspective. The compiler sees an Object object as it was passed into the function. There is nothing to tell the compiler that object is a Rectangle, as its type is never changed to Rectangle.

It would be a syntax error because when you try doing object.width, the compiler will say: "Object doesn't have this field." You instead need to explicitly tell the compiler that object is a Rectangle. Then, it will know you can use object.width.

Consider the compiler to be completely brainless in instances like this, not knowing anything you don't tell it explicitly.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer really crystallized in my mind what @Kayaman was saying.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't know that this `object` has a field called `width`. But `other` *is* a `Rectangle` - thus the compiler knows that there will be a `width` and a `height` field respectively.

I suggest you don't do the cast, use directly the object instead and look at the error you get.